# Receive a wav file from byte streaming in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, wav

I have a java network server and Ruby network client communicating through Sockets 
I use TCPSocket in Ruby
The client requests a certain wav file from the server I can send requests , and I can receive a text stream 
but I don't know how to receive a wav file through sockets and write it

```
      require 'socket'
      require 'timeout'
      require 'wavefile'
      include WaveFile

    def recvwav
      data_socket=TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
      data_socket.puts text
      begin
        writer = Writer.new("my_file.wav", Format.new(:mono, :pcm_16, 44100))
        timeout(10) do
          writer.write(data_socket.recv(100))
      end
      rescue Timeout::Error
        puts "Timed out!"
      end
    end
```

Comment: Pretty much same way you receive a text stream is the way you receive a binary stream, share some code and people might be able to help you

Comment: I add my code to the question

Answer (score 1):

I get my problem solved , but by writing file directly this is my code

```
    data_socket=TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)  
    #send your request

    somefile = File.open("file_name.wav", "wb")
    somefile.write(data_socket.readlines.join)
    somefile.close
```